# How to print array elements in view

Tags: zend-framework

I have an array in my controller:

```
$data = array(
          'a' => "Hay",
          'b' => "Bee",
          'c' => "Sea",
);
$this->view->assign($data);
```

In the view nothing is returned:

```
<?php echo $this->data['a']; ?>
<?php var_dump($this->data); ?>
```

Comment: are you sure that `$this->data` points to  `$data` ? try to `var_dump( $this->data)`

Comment: in your controller change $this->view->assign($data) to
 $this->view->data = $data;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in controller

```
$this->view->data = $data;
```

for better explanation goto [Zend Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.controllers.html)

Comment: Thanks, this also works, `$this->view->assign('data',$data);`